# VBA to check and see if information in one sheet matches information in another

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I need a VBA macro to do the following:

I have two sheets, in sheet1 there is a list in column A that has part numbers. 
On sheet2 column A i have a column where part numbers can be entered. 
What I require is that when a number is entered on sheet2 column A that Sheet1 column A is checked to make sure that the part number entered on sheet2 is listed on somewhere in sheet1 column A?????

Comment: Look into data validation on the data tab.  Then use a custom formula with MATCH.

Answer (score 0):

*I would like to suggest you the following VBA Code will compare two Worksheets, within defined Data Range for Duplicate entries.*

Let me fist explain the Data situation.

Sheet 1 has data in Range A5:A10 and Sheet2 has in Range A10:A15.

If Sheet 2 Range A10:A15 is EQUALs to  Sheet 1 Range A5:A10 then, Message will appear.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Option Explicit

    Dim lngMyRow As Long
    Dim blnAllMatch As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    For lngMyRow = 1 To 6
        If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & lngMyRow + 4) = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lngMyRow + 9) Then
            MsgBox "Data is simillar.", vbExclamation
            blnAllMatch = False
            Exit For
        Else
            blnAllMatch = True
        End If
    Next lngMyRow

    If blnAllMatch = True Then
        MsgBox "Data is different !!", vbInformation
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

**NB:** *You need to alter values in VBA Code Row 6 & 7, according to your Data Range. This code can be used as "Worksheet_Change Event" also.*

**Note,** *This Code was tested by me, before I've posted it here.*

*Hope this help you.*